# Date picker Kalendae in IE8 not switching months or years after date selection

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, date, internet-explorer-8

After I select a date via Kalendae in IE8 like this:

[image]

I can not move to previous/next month nor previous/next year. This is happening on **IE8** on other browsers like chrome and firefox everything works fine!

***In other words the problem occurs after I selected a date. If no previous date is selected the whole thing works fine. I think the problem occurs because IE8 can't change the input or something.***

I have the standalone version of kalendae version 0.4.2, the code can be found in my gist here:
https://gist.github.com/YOUConsulting/2910373f3650fa86d651

I have implemented it like this in my html:

```
<label for="personal_info[BIRTHDATE]">Date of Birth <small>(Example: 31/10/1985)</small></label>

<input class="auto-kal" data-kal="format:'DD/MM/YYYY',weekStart:1,direction:'today-past',blackout:'future'" id="personal_info[BIRTHDATE]" name="personal_info[BIRTHDATE]" style="margin-bottom:-3px;" type="text" value="">
```

Thanks to anyone who can help me.

Kr,
Vince

Comment: People who want to test this can download the example file from here: https://github.com/ChiperSoft/Kalendae and use my JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not 100% clean but seems to be working.

Replace line 854 by:

```
//create the close button
if (opts.closeButton) {
    $closeButton = util.make('a', {'class':classes.closeButton}, self.container);
    util.addEvent($closeButton, 'click', function () {
        if(util.isIE8())
            self.hide();
        $input.blur();
    });
}
```

and line 874 by

```
this._events.documentMousedown = util.addEvent(window.document, 'mousedown', function (event, target) {
    noclose = false;
    if(util.isIE8())
        self.hide();
});
```